# Share Compiled Razor between applications

Tags: razorengine

In our CMS, we are using RazorEngine heavily for rendering each section of the page. On the same platform we host about 30 portals that are hosted on IIS in multiple application pools. Also we are having 10 web servers in a web farm.
Now, what is the best way to skip compiling each Razor at run-time since it is getting cached in the memory and the same process (which is time consuming) is getting done per application pool and per server since they are using exactly the same set of .csthml files and data models.
There is no need to change the Razor files at run-time.
So, the best option might be to compile the Razor files at build time. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that compiling views into separate dll's would do fine : http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/